# Decreasing decoration gameobjects performance cost

Tags: unity-game-engine

A lot of my gameobjects in my scene only serve as decoration. In blender it shows me that I have about 100k vertices and in unity it says that I have 240k. After initialization nothing about them gets changed, not even their shadows change. 
**Ideas:** 
Some of the meshes are doubled but I assumed it wouldn't change much if I they would derive from the same mesh because it still needs to get loaded to times. 
I already made them static but they are still pretty performance heavy. 
The camera doesn't always move so I thought about creating an image of the current background and setting it as the render texture and setting the background as inactive as long as the camera isn't moving. 
I hope, however, that there's a better solution. 
My settings for the gameobjects' mesh renderer:
[image]

 All of them have the same material:
[image] 
The graphics stats in the editor:
[image]

Comment: You can do whats called billboarding. It simplifies meshes from thousands of verts to single digits. Something like [`this asset`](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/amplify-impostors-119877). Have you also tried GPU instancing the meshes that are exactly the same?

Comment: And yes if your camera moves only in very rare occasions you could definitely give it a shot and render these objects only once to a Ränder texture, disable that camera and only display that rendered texture until you move again, then simply enable the according camera again until you stop moving

Comment: @TEEBQNE I will try your suggestions. Sorry, I should have informed myself better, I haven't heard of GPU instancing.

Comment: @derHugo The camera moves two times every 10-20 seconds. An issue there is that some objects are moving and they wouldn't be see n in this case. Nonetheless, I will try coming up with a work around if TEEBQNE's suggestions aren't enough.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the downvotes. Most questions on the Unity tag get down voted for some reason. You could add more detail, link posts you've referenced and show a setup for the meshes that are an issue.. As for GPU instancing it's not on the mesh, but on the material between each mesh, sorry I didn't explain that. A good forum post to guide you might be [`this one`](https://answers.unity.com/questions/14578/whats-the-best-way-to-reduce-draw-calls.html)